# SettingWithCopyWarning in indexing.py

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on my first Pandas project, and I'm running into what seems to be a very common issue when people are first getting familiar with Pandas: `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I understand the reasoning behind what's going on generally from the other StackOverflow answers, of which there are quite a few; however, I'm not sure how to deal with the problem in my particular case. The lines in question are here.  I've slightly simplified some of the lines that should have no impact whatsoever on what's going on here (e.g. the read_excel).

```
raw_df = pd.read_excel('infile.xlsx')
baseline_df = raw_df[raw_df['oe_aftermarket']=='OEM']
baseline_df = baseline_df.groupby(key_params).sum().reset_index()
starts_with_z = baseline_df['platform'].str.startswith('Z -').fillna(False)
baseline_df[starts_with_z]['platform'] = 'X-' + baseline_df[starts_with_z]['market']
```

Line by line, then, I expect that this code first reads the file from Excel and then grabs the subset of data where the value in the `oe_aftermarket` is equal to `OEM`. It groups by some predetermined set of key parameters, and then isolates those line items where the `platform` column starts with the string `Z -`, filling NA values where Pandas doesn't convert numbers to strings. Finally, those line items with platforms that do start with `Z -` have their platforms replaced by `X-` followed by whatever value is in the `market` column.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the infamous `SettingWithCopyWarning` on the last line:

```
oe_test.py:76: SettingWithCopyWarning: blah blah
```

Replacing the offending line with

```
baseline_df[starts_with_z].loc[:,'platform'] = 'X-' + baseline_df[starts_with_z]['market']
```

as suggested by the previous warning does make a bit of a difference. The same warning gets thrown again, but this time from within indexing.py in Pandas:

```
/home/james/.local/share/virtualenvs/tdg-99-fk6tK/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:537: SettingWithCopyWarning: blah blah`
```

I've tried adding a `.copy()` to the initial line where the copy is made, `baseline_df = raw_df[raw_df['oe_aftermarket']=='OEM']`, but to no avail. I'm generally pretty handy when it comes to fixing code issues, but I'm quite confused at this point, especially since the error is being thrown in Pandas' own code rather than mine.

Any insight anyone has would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using `.loc` with `raw_df.loc[raw_df['oe_aftermarket']=='OEM']`.

Comment: No joy, unfortunately.  Same error in `indexing.py`